# Why can't I connect to a local service from a Go application on Windows

Tags: windows, go, windows-10

I have a Go application which depends on the presence of a local service. There are three initial scenarios in which it could run.

1. service is installed and running already.
2. service is installed, but not running, start service and wait.
3. service is neither installed nor running, use embedded version of service and wait.

To figure out which of these scenarios it is running in, tt checks if the service is running already on the host, and if it's available, it does nothing and everything works. Scenario 1) is obviously in working order, but, if the service is installed on the host but not running, it starts it and waits for the port to become available, and that's where the trouble begins.

Currently, it determines whether this service is ready by waiting until it can make a connection to the port the service is available on.

```
func Available() bool {
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp4", net.JoinHostPort(loopbackInterface(), "8051"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Connecting error:", err)
        }
        if conn != nil {
            conn.Close()
            return true
        }
        // The time it can take for the service to become available is pretty variable, the first time can be 2-3 minutes, subsequent times could only be a few seconds. I'll dial this in more precisely later.
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(i*10) * time.Second)
    }
    return false
}
```

This works reliably on OSX and on GNU/Linux, but when I get to Windows, the service starts, and I can go into powershell and the port does in fact become available with `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8051).OwningProcess`, but somehow, I am never able to make a connection to this port from my application. This seems like absolutely bizarre behavior, however, this is true for both fresh Virtual Machines and hardware. So on Windows only, scenarios 2) and 3) are totally broken.

It seems to me that there is some difference between these systems(Windows application firewall?) that is causing this problem, but I've not been able to confirm any cause or find any solution to the problem.

So how do I: start an external application, wait for a port to become available, and connect to that port from a Go application deployed to a Windows 10 PC?

Comment: Have you checked Windows Firewall and made sure the port has been opened?

Comment: Your PS invocation does not mention host IP or name, so are you sure `loopbackInterface()` returns something which actually can be connected to when joined with the port?

Comment: Also, try simpler thing: fetch `netcat` for Windows (or install `telnet`—it should be available through some obscure-as-always stock "components installer") and try to connect to the relevant host/port using this tool; see what happens. One more thing to add to what @Adrian said: Windows firewall is able to check the owner (credentials) of the process trying to connect, so verify your PS invocation and your checking process are running with the same credentials, and the PS invocation did not somehow elevate the privileges.

Comment: loopbackInterface does actually return the correct interface, and if I replace it with the correct interface as a string literal, the behavior is the same.

Comment: It does look like I have elevated my privileges when I checked for the port to be open with PS. What would that mean for my application though? Wouldn't all the processes started by my application have the same credentials?

Comment: «Wouldn't all the processes started by my application have the same credentials?»—yes, should be so.

Comment: «does actually return the correct interface, and if I replace it with the correct interface»—we may be having a terminological issue here but you're not supposed to have the name of an interface (network card/connection) here: it should be an IP or a hostname.

Comment: kostix the service is listening on 127.0.0.1, loopbackInterface() when used in this context returns this string. When I replace loopbackInterface() with a string literal the one I use is "127.0.0.1"